# How to find string length using scasb in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, strlen

I have a string and am trying to find it's length. I am using rw32-2017. I tried to scan the string using `repe scasb` but it does not change the ZF at all.
Is there a easier way to find the length of a string?

My program:

```
%include "rw32-2017.inc"

section .data
    ; write your data here
    string1 db "how long is this string",0

section .text
main:
    mov ebp, esp
    
    ; write your code here
    mov esi,string1
    mov eax,0
    mov ecx,50      ;max length of string is 50
    mov ebx,ecx
    cld
    repe scasb 
    sub ebx, ecx
    mov eax,ebx
    call WriteUInt8

    ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `SCAS` you should put the address of the string in `EDI`, not `ESI`. And instead of `REPE` you want `REPNE` (repeat while not equal and ecx!=0).

```
mov edi,string1
mov eax,0
mov ecx,50 ;max lenght of string is 50
mov ebx,ecx
cld
repne scasb   ; find AL (0), starting at [ES:EDI]
```

Answer (score 3):

For assemble-time-constant strings, the assembler can calculate the length as a constant integer:

```
string1 db "how long is this string",0
len equ $-string1       ; len = current position - start of string
```

gives length to `len`, including the `0` byte.  (You might want to omit the terminating `0` byte if you only use explicit-length operations on the string, like `write` system calls, or at least make the `0` not part of the length you count).

You can use it as an immediate constant:

```
mov edx, len
```